# How to make an extension for dictionary that allows use of the subscript with a dynamic key?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {   

    func date(forKey key: String) -> Date? {

        return self[key] as? Date

    }

}

let dictionary: [String : Any] = ["mydate" : Date(), "otherkey" : "Rofl"]

dictionary.date(forKey:"mydate")  // should return a Date? object
```

// i get the error ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

How can i make my extension allow me to give a key and use the subscript with not a literal, but a "dynamic" key in the form of String?

Comment: Just replace `key: String` with `key: Key`.

Comment: Note that `Value: Any` is a redundant constraint. I also see no reason to constrain the `Key` to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` – what difference does it make if `Key` isn't `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the unneeded constraints and directly use `Key` or `Value` types wherever you see fit.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func date(forKey key: Key) -> Date? {
        return self[key] as? Date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `key: String` with `key: Key`:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {

    func date(forKey key: Key) -> Date? {

        return self[key] as? Date

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a little sugar syntax by "proxy-ing" the date query to something like this:

```
struct DictionaryValueProxy<DictKey: Hashable, DictValue, Value> {
    private let dictionary: [DictKey:DictValue]

    init(_ dictionary: [DictKey:DictValue]) {
        self.dictionary = dictionary
    }

    subscript(key: DictKey) -> Value? {
        return dictionary[key] as? Value
    }
}

extension Dictionary {
    var dates: DictionaryValueProxy<Key, Value, Date> { return DictionaryValueProxy(self) }
}
```

You can then ask the dictionary for it's dates in an seamless way:

```
let dict: [Int:Any] = [1: 2, 3: Date()]
dict.dates[1]                            // nil
dict.dates[3]                            // "Dec 7, 2016, 5:23 PM"
```